# Remove childElements one-by-one in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, removechild

I have:

```
<div id="alerts">
    <div class="alert">alert 1</div>
    <div class="alert">alert 2</div>
</div>
```

and want to remove these alerts one-by-one **after 4000 ms** by an **interval of 500 ms** in **pure JavaScript**.

I have this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alerts = document.getElementById( 'alerts' );
    if( alerts ){
        alert = alerts.getElementsByClassName( 'alert' );
        setTimeout( function(){
            for( var i=0; i < alert.length; i++ ){
                ( function( i ){
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        alerts.removeChild( alert[i] );
                    }, 500);
                }
                )(i);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }
}
```

I think this is not the right way of using `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a [live collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which means when a selected element is removed or changed in the dom the referred collection also changes.

So in your example when you start the `alert` has 2 elemnets, but when the first element is removed then `alert` will have only 1 element but you are referring to `alert[1]` which will be undefined.

So the solution will be is to remove the first element from the array.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var alerts = document.getElementById('alerts');
  if (alerts) {
    alert = alerts.getElementsByClassName('alert');
    setTimeout(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < alert.length; i++) {
        (function(i) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            alerts.removeChild(alert[0]);
          }, i * 500); //need increasing timeouts
        })(i);
      }
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="alerts">
  <div class="alert">alert 1</div>
  <div class="alert">alert 2</div>
</div>
```

---

But you can use setInterval() to solve this in a better way like

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var alerts = document.getElementById('alerts');
  if (alerts) {
    var alert = alerts.getElementsByClassName('alert');
    setTimeout(function() {
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
        alerts.removeChild(alert[0]);
        if (!alert.length) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      }, 1000);
    }, 3000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="alerts">
  <div class="alert">alert 1</div>
  <div class="alert">alert 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the second snippet in your answer. I was typing my answer only after I saw the first way you did it

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach would be to use `setInterval`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  alerts = document.getElementById('alerts');
  if (alerts) {
    alert = alerts.getElementsByClassName('alert');
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (alert.length) {
        alerts.removeChild(alert[alert.length - 1]);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }

    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="alerts">
  <div class="alert">alert 1</div>
  <div class="alert">alert 2</div>
</div>
```